# Examples and physical materials that are helpful for teaching GIS principles

Tags: coordinate-system, references, gis-principle, spatial-analysis

I am collecting some of the resources and materials that are helpful when teaching the basics of GIS to extend my current toolbox. Some of those I use myself when teaching introductory courses. I am looking for other hands-on materials (preferably, non-digital) that can help understand some of the GIS/geography related concepts such as projections, spatial analysis, and others.

Probably one of the most famous examples is a trick with an [orange peel](https://youtu.be/LN_tCKdl9cE?t=43) when a navel orange is being peeled to demonstrate the projection from a globe to a flat map. National Geographic has detailed instructions on this excellent tutorial along with other materials for constructing 3D models of Earth from paper ([read more about Investigating Map Projections](http://nationalgeographic.org/activity/investigating-map-projections/)).

I also use an overhead projector for demonstrating with transparent plastic sheets how a route can be drawn (with a pen) while avoiding forbidden territories over multiple layers (conceptually, path analysis and geographic overlay illustrations). Great guidelines are available in the book [The Really Practical Guide to Primary Geography](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0748726179).

What is great about these examples is that students can try this themselves - to see the holes in the orange peel and to see how hard it is to find a route taking into consideration the areas of multiple sheet layers.

What are other known hands-on materials that can help illustrate spatial/GIS concepts? Things that are related to computer science (such as database management) that have something related to geography would also fit.